# Can't find module tsne in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, conda, torch, tsne

In Pycharm, I can't find module tsne in settings. How to download in pycharm?
When I try to run command in cmd as:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tsne
```

The command exits with this error:

```
C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>conda install -c conda-forge tsne
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https//conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64'
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please try searching the CondaHTTPError - that is very common for Windows users and unlikely needs a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with pip - [tsne Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tsne/)

```
pip install tsne
```

If it's an issue with conda API then download binaries from [conda tsne](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tsne/files) and then

```
conda install c:path/path/to/downloaded_binary
```

In the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/tsne/#:%7E:text=pip%20install%20tsne-,From%20conda%3A,-conda%20install%20%2Dc) for conda they have mentioned like this. so try if the above snippet doesn't work

```
conda install -c maxibor tsne
```

Comment: When using pip, make sure to be inside of the venv used by the PyCharm project (that could be the reason the module is not found in the first place)

Comment: I am facing same problem and can't resolve it. Help me out!